# Do not send mails with duplicate subjects

Tags: email, smtp, duplicates

we've got different processes that send mails in case of issues encountered (e.g. not enough permissions to perform an operation on a certain order item). This works fine to the point that sometimes identical messages are sent every 5 minutes. In our environment it is very difficult to synchronize the email sending on application layer (actually there are different applications sending out email, so we'd have to touch every application if we were to implement this inside application layer).

It would seem logical for me that filtering out mails (by duplicate subjects) is best done within the email layer, e.g. the application receiving the SMTP requests.

Yet we'd also prefer not to go down to SMTP layer by ourselves, rather use an existing service/application.

Is anybody aware of a web mailer (like googlemail) which does this kind of filtering? it would be ok for us the pay for such a service, so being "free as in beer" would be nice, but being not free is not a showstopper.

Thanks in advance
Holger

Answer (score 0):

I find the idea of filtering duplicate e-mail message by the `Subject:` header quite worrisome. If they are produced by multiple applications, how can you be certain that the *content* of the messages is duplicated and that you are not unwittingly dropping important notifications?

The only *unique* feature of a message that can be used to filter out duplicates is its `Message-ID:` header. If that header is the same for two messages, then it's usually reasonable to assume that they are copies of the same original message - e.g. one received directly and one that was CC'ed to a mailing list.

That said, you can do pretty much anything you want on most SMTP servers - at least those that are based on a Unix-like OS. For example, [Postfix can use custom shell scripts for filtering](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).

You can, for example, use [formail](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/formail1.html) to extract the body of each message and produce its
MD5 hash. Comparing the message body hashes along with the `Date:`, `Subject:`, `From:`, `To:` and `Cc:` headers at the same time is a good start to detect real duplicates.

Comment: I don't believe that the described messages are *bytewise* equal, just that they're functionally duplicates.  (If they're being generated by different sources, it's very hard to end up with bytewise duplicates.)  But the remainder of the answer seems sound, even if it's just deduping based on `Subject`.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the comments; The contents WILL be identical because they refer to the same type of issue.

Comment: sorry, previous comment got corrupted by my network connection

---

Hi,

thanks all for your time and comments. I'll have a look into postfix, although I'd rather prefer not to install any mail transfer agent on our side (for security reasons).

My comments to your comments:

The sent emails WILL be equal in terms of what has to be done by tech support ("functionally identical"). However, the mails will definitely have distinct message-ids.

Comment: The term "multiple applications" may be confusing

On the one hand, there are identical binaries running on different servers. These applications do the same thing, but as I said possible on different hardware or even in different networks. That's why it's difficult to synchronize messages within one application. 

otoh we have different kinds of applications like automated offline processes, web sites or monitoring. Some of those applications are developed by ourselves, but not all. That's why I'm looking rather for a solution on SMTP level as opposed to modifying each of these applications.

Comment: Why can duplicate emails be ignored? First or all, we're responsible for the subjects, and we can modify them.

Comment: Secondly, if a problem occurs, it often occurs multiple times. Let me explain why:

Comment: We're running automated processes that work on flight bookings ("PNRs"). There's a concept of queues that contain PNRs that shall be processed. In some (rare) cases, a PNR (booking) on such a queue cannot be processed at all (e.g. due to invalid security settings).

Comment: This is something we detect, and we send an email to support, e.g. "Booking ABCDEF cannot be accessed". However, since the booking cannot be touched at all (it cannot be removed from the queue), the next time our process works on such a queue, It will encounter the same problem with the same PNR. So we'll send another "Booking ABCDEF cannot be accessed". We're running our processes every 5 minutes, so the number of mails sent can be enormous.

Comment: Of course, it could happen that our automation processes see the same booking on different dates/days, and the problem is actually a different one, so we should get the message more than once. That could be solved by adding the date to the mail subject (remember, we can change the mail subjects).

Comment: Aplogies for the high number of comments, but the UI of stackoverflow.com won't let me put everythign in one comment.

Best regards
Holger

Comment: @user214984: I think it would be better if you copied all this information in your question (use the `edit` link) and simply deleted the comments.